# Changing titles in Uploader for "Posts"

Tags: uploads, media-library

When I click the "add media button" within the Visual Editor in the "Add a New Post" page in my blog, there are some titles I would like rename,

http://puu.sh/ikJ9g/79e0cb4497.png

1. I would like renamed is "Insert Media" to "Upload Content"
2. I would like renamed "Upload Files" to "Upload" & "Media Library" to "Your Content"

Answer (score 1):

you have the "media_view_strings" filter for this :

```
add_filter("media_view_strings", function ($strings, $post) {
    $strings["insertMediaTitle"] = "Upload Content";
    $strings["uploadFilesTitle"] = "Upload";
    $strings["mediaLibraryTitle"] = "Your Content";

    return $strings;
}, 10, 2);
```